# Map data structure in strict mode

Tags: typescript, strict

I am using strict mode for the following code.
Trying to assign an object value from a Map.
It is granted that the value I am getting from the Map isn't undefined but strict mode giving the following error `Type A[]|undefined isn't assignable to type A[]`.
How can I pass this compiler issue?

```
let key = "foo"
leaderboardRecords: A[] = [];
leaderboardRecordsbyRegion: Map<string, A[]> = new Map<string, A[]>();
if (!leaderboardRecordsbyRegion.has(key)) {
        leaderboardRecordsbyRegion.set(key, fetchData());
    }
leaderboardRecords = leaderboardRecordsbyRegion.get(key);
```

Comment: There is highly likely chance that the return type of function `fetchData()` would be `A[]|undefined`. So error says that types are not matching. Simple

Comment: You should add [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so that people can understand your problem clearly.

Comment: Use the [Non-null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator), `leaderboardRecords = leaderboardRecordsbyRegion.get(key)!;`

Comment: @DecPK `fetchData()` returns `a promise<A[]>`

Comment: @PhilopateerNabil can you add your full code where this problem is reproducible

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it in the end.
I added or empty array to pass the compiler.

```
leaderboardRecords = leaderboardRecordsbyRegion.get(key) || [];
```